# Unity + php + database data output issue

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuPhx.png), the log is print pretty!
but, in unity the output is wrong.
How can I solve it?

And this is my source:

```
private void Awake()
    {
        info = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }


    private IEnumerator Start()
    {

        WWW dash = new WWW("http://localhost/test.php");
        yield return dash;

        string[] Separators = new string[] { "\n" };
        string[] lines = dash.text.Split(Separators, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        info.Clear();
        for(int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject tmp = Instantiate(scorepre);
            string[] parts = lines[i].Split(',');
            string Name = parts[1];
            string Detail = parts[2];
            info.Add(Name, Detail);
            Debug.Log(Name + " - " + Detail);

            named.GetComponent<Text>().text = Name;
            detailed.GetComponent<Text>().text = Detail;

            tmp.transform.SetParent(infoParent);
        }
```

Comment: were are the named and detailed game objects defined?

Comment: private Dictionary<string, string> info;

    public Transform infoParent;

    public GameObject scorepre;

    public GameObject named;

    public GameObject detailed;
These are all my defines.

Comment: so this script is setting the text of the same object multiple times because the named and detailed references don't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the named and detailed object always seem to refer to the same object.

**edit**
After rethinking how you might have linked your objects i think the order of the code is incorrect.

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    WWW dash = new WWW("http://localhost/test.php");
    yield return dash;

    string[] Separators = new string[] { "\n" };
    string[] lines = dash.text.Split(Separators, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    info.Clear();
    for(int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
    {         
        if (i > 0) // only copy the object after the first text is set
        {
            GameObject tmp = Instantiate(scorepre);
            tmp.transform.SetParent(infoParent);
        }

        string[] parts = lines[i].Split(',');
        string Name = parts[1];
        string Detail = parts[2];
        info.Add(Name, Detail);
        Debug.Log(Name + " - " + Detail);

        //first change the text
        named.GetComponent<Text>().text = Name;
        detailed.GetComponent<Text>().text = Detail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm so late. Thank you for your answer!!. but it doesn't work...

Comment: I have a mistake. The source code is perfectly good for me!!!! Thank you very much